# what I should use as responseType

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, restful-architecture

I created a REST Web Service and one method consumes an Object and produces a boolean when adding a REST client to another Java Application I don't know what I should insert as responseType

here is the @POST method in REST WS:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean validatePaiement(Paiement pay) {
   return nameStorage.validatePaiement(pay);
}
```

here is the generated method in the Class NewJerseyClient with NetBeans in client app:

```
public <T> T validatePaiement(Object requestEntity, Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), responseType);
}
```

here my simple main class :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Paiement pay = new Paiement(111, 111, "yasin", 111, "yasin", "yasin");
    System.out.println(new NewJerseyClient().validatePaiement(pay, Boolean.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As responseType you pass class of value which return method in you REST WS bean.

Comment: which is should be in this situation?

Comment: run:
  Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
   at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:929)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:770)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:90)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)

Comment: Server returns HTTP error with code 500, which mean internal server error. See logs on server side, there should be exception in server log.